# using multiple markers to position a single object unity3D & Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have just started developing with Unity3D and Vuforia to create augmented reality applications. I was wondering if anyone has tried or seen examples of a single augmented object e.g. a cube being generated when several markers are detected.

The idea would be to place 3 AR Markers in a triangular shape and when all 3 are detected draw a cube in the middle. Most projects I have seen seem to use a single marker corresponding to a single object. The idea here is that all 3 markers would be required to draw the object.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: vuforia is fine but why not try openCV?  https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088  fantastic asset there.

Comment: I had tried openCV but found it was a bit of a problem. Since I posted this I've managed to do what I needed in Unity and it seemed far easier than the openCV option.

Comment: u mean with Vuforia right?

Comment: Yes I used Unity with the Vuforia package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at this page https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/how-many-targets-can-i-track-vuforia. You can track many marker at once using the max simulataneous tracking in QCARBehaviour but it will depend on your hardware.

Once you get to track them all three, each marker is a game object with target tracking component, each of the object will receive the event:

```
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus) 
{
    if(newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    {
        OnTrackingFound();  
    }
    else
    {
        OnTrackingLost();
    }
}
```

from the ITrackableEventHandler interface. You can then implement OnTrackingFound/Lost as you need.

In your case, a controller would listen to the events from all three trackers and when all three are on, it displays item.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a look